# How could i only retrieve the first 20 items of a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

[https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/618314979459989526/702360548632821852/unknown.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vceng.png)

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Pyyh/sdsv.py", line 10, in 
    print("Last Item: ", lst_data[20])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please post the code and not the screenshot. This is against the rules.

Comment: Oh no! not the rules

Answer (score 1):

Python indexing starts from 0. You are reading 20 items and for last index, the value given is 20. Index value of 20 means 21st element from the list which doesnt exists and hence the error. It should be 19. Another easy way is to use `-1` as index value to get the last element in the list.